# SVG marker scale only one dimension with stroke width

Tags: svg

I have SVG lines of variable thickness, and all of them have a marker in the form of an arrow at the end, like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uxqK/306/). Per default, `markerUnits` is set to `strokeWidth`, which scales both (!) dimensions of the arrow according to the stroke width of the line.

I, on the other hand, would like to only scale the y dimension, as depicted in the very beautiful paint drawing below (should behave like the orange arrows, the red is not what I want).

[image]

The reason for this is that I want to model quantities of people moving from one place to another, but the arrows should all have strictly the same length (i.e. line length is not a visual cue, only the stroke width is).

Is there any way to do this "dynamically"; i.e. without recalculating the path of the marker all the time? Is there a library that can do this, e.g. D3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the stroke-width, scale the line in the y direction instead e.g.

```html
<svg width="90%" height="90%">
    <defs>
        <marker orient="auto" viewBox="-.1 -5 10 10" id="g-arrowhead-rep">
            <path fill="#808600" class="g-marker g-rep" d="M-.1,-5L4,0L-.1,5"></path>
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <path id="k9ffd8001" d="M10,20,200,20" stroke="#808600" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(0 0 0)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" marker-end="url(#g-arrowhead-rep)"></path>
        <path id="k9ffd8001" d="M10 80 200 80" stroke="#808600" stroke-width="10" transform="translate(0, -80) scale(1,2) " stroke-linecap="butt"
        stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" marker-end="url(#g-arrowhead-rep)"></path>
        
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works, at least in Firefox. In Chrome, the lines/arrows are not displayed at all, and in IE (even IE11), the arrowheads are rounded and way too big. Do you know a solution for this, too? http://jsfiddle.net/8uxqK/307/

Comment: OK, the reason why it was not displayed in Chrome was the empty `viewbox` attribute for the svg tag. http://jsfiddle.net/8uxqK/309/ So the only problem that remains is IE. 9-11. :-/